# Plug-in for playlist (m3u8) other than Safari?

Tags: http-live-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play m3u8 playlist in all PC browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516247/how-to-play-m3u8-playlist-in-all-pc-browsers)

I am trying for Video on demand (VOD) using HTTP Live streaming and crate playlist m3u8 file which contains Meta Data with .ts file paths. I cab able to play in Mac Safari at Desktop using video tag in HTML5, but which is not playing Other browser which supports HTML5. Please help me what i missing or what need to be done to play other browsers.

Sri