# How to store HLS/m3u8 Formatted video offline (on browser) to play when internet is not available?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

**Goal**

To build a feature to make videos available offline. A feature like *youtube offline videos* but on browser.

**Problem**

Is it possible to make `HLS formatted` (also known as `.m3u8`) videos available to user offline on there browsers?

Is it possible to store HLS video in users browser (in Indexed db etc) and then play directly from there (At least for a short term period)?

I have crawled web and searched for a solution but found nothing and now I am putting my problem before the amazing SOF community. Please help or guide me.

Comment: Have you do any research with the video players like flowplayer, hls.js or jwplayer?.  Maybe by increasing the buffer preloaded, like a lot. It may do the trick. If existing video players do not support it, it will be possible but maybe it will require a big effort.

Comment: I have seen `hsl.js` and it is good to for playing HLS videos but what I need is to store them for a sometime just like we do in youtube app.

@jolumg I found an article that has shown to store a m`.mp4` locally but I have my videos in `.m3u8` format. http://www.codingsection.com/create-your-own-offline-video-playback-system-like-youtube.html

Comment: Well an m3u8 file is just a text file, defining something like the playlist of small chunks to be played. These chunks the .TS files are actually the  video segments. I mentioned the players because they already read that m3u8 file and requests the proper  .TS files.

Comment: @jolumg you are right `m3u8` is just a text file that contains info about the video segments and players like `hsl.js` read it and play the content. If I download all the segments and store them in `indexeddb` then how will I play the video?

Comment: yes this is the difficult part :-). This is why I was suggesting to use some of the existing video players. They have the logic to do that, from my point of view it is easier to modify the behaviour (or even the code in the case of hls.js). I think it might be possible to load the video (setting a big buffer to load the whole video) when there is connection and play it afterwards. But you need to keep the browser window open.

Comment: Did you solve the problem in any way?

Comment: @ThomasG. I tried a lot however could not find any solution. :(

Comment: @VikasBansal How about today? I am also working on this. Did you find a workaround or a different solution?